# Why can I run my app VSCode but not correctly in CLI?, its a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, visual-studio-code

I'm building a web application in spring boot.

The development environment is Gradle and I am using visual studio code.

I'm using visual studio code's debug function, spring boot dashboard, and when I start the application, the page is displayed correctly, but when I make the web application a jar file and run it with `java -jar`, it doesn't work with some page transitions.

Please tell me what I should do to make it work and what is happening.
(I think that spring boot can't find the some path, but I don't know what is and how to fix it.)

Here's the page I was on when I accessed 「localhost:8080/gallery」

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Sep 01 23:09:16 JST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

The following is the error I get when I use java -jar to access a specific gallery page.

```
2020-09-01 23:09:14.129  INFO 15464 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-01 23:09:14.143  INFO 15464 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 14 ms
Check image file path
2020-09-01 23:09:16.656 ERROR 15464 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.example.sweepea.GetImage.getImage(GetImage.java:23) ~[classes!/:na]
        at com.example.sweepea.swepeaController.getGallery(swepeaController.java:21) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
```

The methods in the controller class are as follows. 「index」and「about」is work.

```
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String getIndex(){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/gallery")
    public String getGallery(Model model){
            List<String> imagePath = new GetImage().getImage(new File("src/main/resources/static/images"));
            model.addAttribute("imagePath", imagePath);
            return "gallery";
        }

    @GetMapping("/about")
    public String getAbout(){
            return "about";
        }
}
```

GetImage class are as follw.
It is get `.jpg` images , add List and return.

```
@Service
public class GetImage {
    String month = "202009";
    List<String> pathname = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    List<String> getImage(File file){
        File[] filelist = file.listFiles();
        
        

        if(filelist == null){
            System.out.println("Check image file path");
        }

        for (File tmpFile : filelist){
            if(tmpFile.isDirectory()){
                month = tmpFile.getName();
                //System.out.println(month);
                //pathname.add(month);
                getImage(tmpFile);
            
            }else{
                String imagePath = "images/" + month + "/" + tmpFile.getName();
                if(imagePath.substring(imagePath.length() - 3).equals("jpg")){
                    pathname.add(imagePath);
                    //System.out.println(imagePath);
                }
            }

        }
        return pathname;
    }
}
```

gallery.html

```
 <body>
        <div id="content">
            <header class="page_header wrapper" >
                <h1><a th:href="@{'/index'}"><img class="logo" th:src="@{images/logo.svg}" alt=""></a></h1>
                <nav class="main_nav">
                    <ul>
                        <ii><a th:href="@{'/index'}">TOP</a></ii>
                        <ii><a th:href="@{'/gallery'}">GALLERY</a></ii>
                        <ii><a th:href="@{'/about'}">ABOUT</a></ii>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <main>
                <div class="edition">
                    <p>sub title</p>
                </div>
            
            
            
            <h2 class="mounth">Gallery</h2>
            <div class="grid item">
                    <a th:each="image : ${imagePath}" th:href="@{${image}}"><img th:src="@{${image}}" alt=""></a>

            </div>

            
            
            
            </main>
        </body>
```

source tree is like that

```
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── example
    │   │           └── sweepea
    │   │               ├── DemoApplication.java
    │   │               ├── GetImage.java
    │   │               ├── Test.java
    │   │               └── swepeaController.java
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── application.properties
    │       ├── static
    │       │   ├── logo.svg
    │       │   ├── images
    │       │   │   ├── 201910
    │       │   │   │   ├── 1.jpg
    │       │   │   ├── 201911
    │       │   │   ├── 201912
    │       │   │   │   ├── 1.jpg
    │       │   │   ├── 202001
    │       │   │   ├── 202002
    │       │   │   │   ├── 1.jpg
    │       │   │   ├── 202003
    │       │   │   │   ├── 1.jpg
    │       │   │   ├── 202004
    │       │   │   │   ├── 1.jpg
    │       │   │   ├── 202005
    │       │   │   │   ├── 1.jpg
    │       │   │   ├── 202006
    │       │   │   ├── 202007
    │       │   │   ├── 202008
    │       │   │   │   ├── 1.jpg
    │       │   │   ├── 202009
    │       │   │   ├── logo.svg
    │       │   │   └── logo_favicon.png
    │       │   └── style.css
    │       └── templates
    │           ├── about.html
    │           ├── gallery.html
    │           ├── index.html
    │           └── video.html
    └── test
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    └── sweepea
                        └── DemoApplicationTests.java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you package you application in a jar, it's no longer dependent on the source code.

If you start your application using `java -jar ...` in another folder or on another server, then `new File("src/main/resources/static/images")` will no longer work.

I think it will work when you execute `java -jar ...` in the root folder of your project, but that's probably not a long-term solution.

Maven considers the `src/main/resources` folder as an input folder for files that need to be included in the jar, so after packaging, those files will be available from java as `getClass().getResource("/static/images/202008/1.jpg")`, and that's how they will be served in Spring Boot (using the ResourceHttpRequestHandler, without the `static/` prefix).

If you want to add images later without having to rebuild and repackage your application, it's better to use an absolute server path like `"C:\gallery\images"` or `"/opt/gallery/images"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I created a directory on the server as you told me and placed the images on the server and it loaded!
I've also confirmed that I was able to load it by executing it with java -jar in the project's root directory.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
List<String> imagePath = new GetImage().getImage(new File("src/main/resources/static/images"));
```

is the problem. The resources should always be read from within the Jar file, not by specifying path, either an absolute one or relative to whatever directory your run your app from.

[This article](https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) shows how to properly read file from the resources folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I see that the resource folder can't be accessed by path specification if I package it into a jar.
I also read the article in the link you gave me.
I see that I can use "getClass().getClassLoader()" to access the files in the jar file.
I don't understand how to do this yet, so I'm going to try it this weekend.